# VBA proper case code

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Can anyone explain why this code returns a Run-time error'91' ?

```
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

Set rng = Selection

For Each cell In rng

Next cell

If Not cell.HasFormula Then

End If

cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(cell.Value)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a brief description of what you are trying to accomplish and what you have attempted to resolve this.

Comment: Your loop does not do anything cell will always be nothing at the end.  the Next Cell should be at the end of the code, as it denotes where the loop should end.  The End IF should be after the cell.Value = ...  It appears you Just threw things together without understanding how they work.

Comment: You could also do this with one line: `Selection.Value = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("INDEX(PROPER(" & Selection.Address & "),)")`

Comment: @Scott Craner a very succinct solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
For Each cell In rng

Next cell
```

This steps through each element of the selected range and does... nothing. When the loop is finished, i.e. the code has stepped through each element, the value stored in the object `cell` is cleared.

```
If Not cell.HasFormula Then

End If
```

Now, `cell` is an empty variable, i.e. it's value is `Nothing`. `Nothing` does not have any properties, specifically, it has no `HasFormula` property

The code I think you want is:

```
For Each cell In rng
    If Not cell.HasFormula Then
        cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(cell.Value)
    End If
Next cell
```

I should add that I've not checked if this code is actually going to run. It's just the "correct" order of execution of the commands you've written.